# Databases in central repository

Tags: android

I'm creating an application that helps staffs in my college to take attendance and term marks calculation in a easy way , for this I need my data to be stored in database in central place so that more than one staff(from different mobile) can access student details from their mobile. My knowledge is up to storing the data in local database using mysql .I have no idea how to make a central place to store the data.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your app Firebase Realtime database or Firestore database:-

Firebase Realtime link :- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database

Firebase Firestore link :- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

you can use these 2 databases for your best experience if you don't have back-end team.